# How do organize your arguments in your functions?

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

I am an apologist of clean and readable code, therefore I find that a lot of arguments passed to functions usually do mean nothing, and people need to go through the functions to understand what they are doing and receiving.

Per example:

```
<?php
function hi($name, $age, $description) {
    echo $name . ' - ' . $age . ' - ' . $description;
}

hi('John', 21, 'I\'m a builder');
?>
```

Should something like this be a better approach?

```
<?php
function hi($options) {
    echo $options['name'] . ' - ' . $options['age'] . ' - ' . $options['description'];
}

hi(array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'age' => 21,
    'description' => 'I\'m a builder'
));    
?>
```

What is your opinion on this?

Comment: I opt for the array approach seeing that in common usage you may already have these in an array like POST or row from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that too many arguments are a code smell. Only not in the same way as you.

They are a code smell because it might mean the function / method is doing too much.

However if you do the latter you don't really fix anything. At least not what you are trying to fix:

> and people need to go through the functions to understand what they are doing and receiving.

You second example does not fix this at all. It only makes it harder to understand what it does, because instead of being to able to look at the signature of the function now I really have to look at the body of the function to see what on earth the thing needs and does.

When I look at the signature of:

```
function hi($name, $age, $description)
```

it is clear the function expects a name, age and description. However when looking at the signature of:

```
function hi($options)
```

I will have no idea what it needs. `$options` can be just about anything.

Another disadvantage of your second approach is that you have no way ever to add [type hints](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) to arguments.

<sub><sub>Don't get me wrong. There are situations where it is perfectly fine to pass an entire array to a function, but I just don't feel this is one of them</sub></sub>

What worries me more in your code is not the fact that there are three arguments, but rather that the function `echo`s data directly instead of `return`ing data. This makes it *very* inflexible.

Comment: That function was just an example. In the function declaration you see what variables you need and whatever each argument represents. However when passing values to them you have no idea what are you passing. However in the second option you explicitly say what you want to pass in the key of the array.

Comment: No you don't explicitly say anything. You just have a function that says: I want an array. And that's it. When calling your function you use values to see what it needs. If you look at your function next week you are clueless what `$options` should contain.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, PHP 5.6 just added new ways to pass arguments to functions!

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics

You can use the "..." operator to pass in an array of arguments.

The traditional option was to use your example and make sure you comment your code correctly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How does this help OPs specific use case (either of the approaches)?

Comment: Perhaps because if you only need to pass one argument you can pass it without using an array? In fact you could do this for any number of arguments. You no longer need to explicitly declare an array or object. It's really just another option that's all.